# PHP preg_match everything except commas?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$regex = "/(.+),(.+);/";
$input = "somestring, 234, sometring5";
preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

I've tried to make it like this:

```
$regex = "/(.^,+),(.^,+);/";
$input = "somestring, 234, sometring5";
preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

But it doesn't work, because I thought that `^,` means except commas, but why it doesn't work?

Because I want to group them by commas, but the commas are symbols itself that the parser gets how to avoid this?

Comment: This only works with character classes. `[^,]` will match everything aside commas. Outside square brackets the `^` means "beginning of the string or line".

Comment: If an answer we gave solved your problem please consider accepting it, so other people will know what helped.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a modified version of your RegEx](http://regex101.com/r/aS2qS7/1), with some explanations for each modifier.

And for those not willing to visit the link:
A RegEx to match all words in a sentence is `/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/g`

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` means match all non symbol characters (a-z, A-Z and 0-9)
- `*` means match it as many repeating times as possible
- `g` modifier (the `/g` at the end) means match as many as possible inside the string; don't just stop at the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You could just split the string on `,` and trim the result:

```
$matches = array_map('trim', explode(',', $input));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/([^,])/g";
$input = "somestring, 234, sometring5";
preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

will get you everything except commas.

Comment: Everything except commas != All word characters